# What does "water rich area" mean?

Tags: meaning, geography

I am unsure how to specifically define a water-rich area. I assume that it is an area of water surplus but I am led to believe it has a more specific definition for I have been asked it as a separate question.

It is given in the context of this sentence:

> The government is expected to allow companies in water-rich areas to make money from selling it to drier regions

I have done a [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=deffine+water+rich+area&ie=&oe=) and nothing comes up straight away, and I haven't been able to find a specific definition for it.

Is it exactly the same as the definition for "water surplus"?

Comment: Hello, Jake. There may be a domain-specific definition for 'water-rich', including statistical requirements, but this would not be general English usage if not given in major online dictionaries. I'd say your question is off-topic here. You might look for a precise definition in business or geological documents, or contact the authors to see if they were using a precise definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you for the explanation, would it be possible this question may be acceptable on [earth science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) as a more subject-related site?

Comment: I've no idea, Jake. Try it. It might be a legal term (which a science site wouldn't welcome either), it might be a term well-defined in earth science, or it might just be a loosely defined description.

Comment: I agree with Ashworth.  I tried to answer, and got tangled up in water compacts (e.g., The Colorado River Compact) the pricing of water and water conservation and gave up.  That is, a surplus is not forever, which is why  Sen. Jackson blocked even discussion of [diversion of any water from the Columbia River](http://articles.latimes.com/1990-05-04/local/me-181_1_columbia-river-water)

Comment: 'Well-watered' 'water-rich' 'over-watered' and 'flooded' will be something like the spectrum of possibilities.

Comment: See also [this discussion: "Word for a Country that Has Enough Water for Drinking, Crops, Forests, &c."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441008/what-does-water-rich-area-mean/441077).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, water-rich means having a surplus of water, at least in this context. I read the article this sentence is from and thought of no other meaning.

I found one instance where water-rich is quantifiable:

> Turkey, located in a semi-arid part of the world, is not rich in freshwater resources, nor does it have the greatest wealth of water resources in the region; compared to water-rich areas (i.e., **those with 10,000 cubic meters of water per capita annually**) such as North America and Western Europe, it has only about one fifth (1,500 cubic meters) of the water available per capita.

This quanta is from [Turkish legislation](https://www.loc.gov/law/help/water-law/turkey.php), so I'm not sure if the value carries over to other countries. I hope this helps.